# How to get access to the bucket created via cloudformation in my lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a lambda and a S3 via cloudformation template. for the bucket , I pass in a parameter for the bucketName. I want to access this bucket in my python code for the lambda function. how can i do this?

cloudformation template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Sample SAM Template 

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Parameters:
  bucketName:
     Default: somename
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: !Sub '${bucketName}-${AWS::AccountID}'

  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
    Environment:
      Variables:
        s3bucketName: !GetAtt S3Bucket
```

lambda_handler function

```
import boto3
import os
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
aws4auth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,credentials.secret_key,region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
                    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

//get access to the S3 bucket created??
```

Comment: The most common option is to supply the bucket name to the Lambda function via environment variable. Add [Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html) to your `AWS::Serverless::Function`.

Comment: @jarmod - updated my answer. this should work?

Comment: Looks reasonable. I would generally name it something like S3_BUCKET_NAME.

Comment: @jarmod - thanks just wanted to ask one last question for this. - do i need to make sure s3 is created before the lambda. I'm getting an error in my python code -> keyError 'S3_BUCKET_NAME', i'm using os.environ['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] in the code to access it. – ozil 1 min ago   Edit

Comment: If that Python error is happening in your Lambda function then the environment variable hasn’t been setup correctly. Use the console to see what environment variables were actually created by your CloudFormation stack.

Answer (score 1):

```py
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
objAsString = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

You are also missing policies to access the s3 bucket from the lambda.

```yaml
HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Environment:
      Variables:
        S3_BUCKET_NAME: !Ref S3Bucket
      Policies:
        - Statement:
          - Effect:
            Action:
              - 's3:GetObject'
              - 's3:ListBucket'
              - 's3:ListBucketMultipartUploads'
              - 's3:PutObject'
            Resource:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}'
```

I would move creation of bucket in separate cloudformation `s3.yaml` and execute it once.

```yaml
....
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: !Sub '${bucketName}-${AWS::AccountID}'

Outputs:
  BucketName:
   Value: !Ref S3Bucket
   Description: 'Bucket name'
   Export:
     Name: s3-bucket-name
```

After that I could import this `s3-bucket-name` in other cloudformation with the lambda.

```
Variables:
   S3_BUCKET_NAME: !ImportValue s3-bucket-name
```

Comment: i updated my answer to add the bucket name under enivornment variables. once i give the s3 access to lambda , like you said. will this set up work?

Comment: Yes bucket name could be access as env variable. I would use `!Ref` instead of `!GetAttr` ...
 
`S3_BUCKET_NAME: !Ref S3Bucket`, updated the example in my answer.

Comment: one last - do i need to make sure s3 is created before the lambda. I'm getting an error in my python code -> keyError 'S3_BUCKET_NAME', i'm using os.environ['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] in the code to access it.

Comment: Yes, you need to create the it first. 
Either you create it with separate cloudformation or use `DependsOn`, so lambda is dependent of creating the bucket first.